# SQL Select Record Using Range of Row Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following database records

```
ID    Weight    Cost
1     3         1.00
2     10        2.00
3     14        3.00
```

What I want is to grab the cost for a given weight. So if my Weight is 5, the cost would be 2.00.

The clarify, the ranges would be:

```
Cost 1.00, weight 0-3
Cost 2.00, weight 4-10
Cost 3.00, weight 11-14
```

I'm not sure what SQL should I use to get the row range, but using columns, I can use `SELECT Cost FROM table1 WHERE column1 BETWEEN x AND y`.

Any suggestions / comments are welcome.

Comment: I didn't get the logic. Can you explain a bit more

Comment: IIt's not clear. Expand test data...

Comment: Did you mean 12 should return 2.00? In that case select top 1... where Weight < xxx order by Weight desc should work

Comment: @JamesZ 12 would return 3.00, since the max weight at price 2.00 is 10.

Comment: There seems to be some discrepancy in logic.

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean by `within the range of ID#2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5307/20

```
declare @Weight int = 5

select top 1 cost
from weightings
where weight >= @Weight
order by weight
```

Comment: For 5 OP wants to get 1.00, your query returns 2.00

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri So he does.  In that case I don't understand the logic he's trying to implement.  :)

Comment: Ah, OP has changed it now.  5 returns 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, perhaps the easiest is to generate a sequence of weights/costs given the intervals present in the table. To do this we can use a numbers/tally-table (in this case I use the `master..spt_values` table which has a suitable range of numbers).

So given a table like:

```
declare @t table (ID int, Weight int, Cost decimal(10,2))
insert @t values (1, 3, 1.00),(2, 10, 2.00),(3, 14, 3.00)
```

We can define two versions of a query (wrapped in a common table expression for convenience). The first version uses the `lag()`window function and requires a version of SQL Server newer than 2012:

```
;with costs1 (weight, cost) as (
    select number, cost 
    from master..spt_values 
    inner join (
       select isnull(LAG(weight) over (order by id)+1,0) low, weight high, cost from @t 
    ) t on number <= t.high and number >= t.low
    where type= 'P'
)

select cost from costs1 where weight = 5;
```

The second version doesn't rely on `lag()` but uses a self-join instead:

```
;with costs2 (weight, cost) as (
    select number, cost
    from master..spt_values 
    inner join (
       select 
       isnull(t2.weight + 1,0) as low, 
       t1.Weight as high, 
       t1.Cost 
    from @t t1 
    left join @t t2 on t1.ID - 1 = t2.ID 
    ) t on number <= t.high and number >= t.low
    where type= 'P'
    )

select cost from costs2 where weight = 5
```

Another option would be to just compute the low/high points for each range and do a query like this:

```
select cost from (
    select isnull(LAG(weight) over (order by id)+1,0) low, weight high, cost from @t
    ) t 
where 5 between low and high
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6606/1) with the queries above.